# Trying to ID this component & where to get a couple of them? Is it a varistor?

Tags: identification, varistor

Here's a photo I made to show back and front of this thing. 
I think it's a varistor.

The main body is roughly 8.5mm in diameter.

I straightened the two legs but I think they are SUPPOSED to have a couple of "twists."

Anybody know something similar in values? It goes onto an old power supply circuit board from around 1996.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Bourns MF-R065 resettable fuse, a very old one since I believe the new ones have the "UL Recognized" symbol on them and the logo looks different.

https://www.buerklin.com/en/Products/Electromechanical/Fuses-and-Breaker/Fuses%2C-Resettable-and-PTC-Fuses/FUSE-MF-R065-2/p/51G2384

Comment: Thanks for your answer sphalung!